# trying to do a series sum in matlab

Tags: matlab

I want to calculate the sum of a series in MATLAB 
The assignment is on the last page question 3 [on this webpage](http://www.usciences.edu/~lvas/mathmethods/math360/MATLAB_programming.pdf)
The series's sum should be pi but when I used MATLAB to prove that it just does not converge to pi

What am I doing wrong in my code?

```
function f = equation(n)
for i=1:n;
    f=4*sum(((-1)^i)/(2*i+1))
    if f >= pi
        break;
    else 
        continue;
    end
end
end
```

EDIT :

```
function f = equation(n)
i=0:n;
f=4*sum((-1).^i ./(2*i+1));
plot(f,'x')
end
```

It does not work to plot(f) , what am I doing wrong ?

Comment: If you `break` as soon as f>3, you will never get closer to pi than 3.

Comment: that is true ,, but f is decresing every time it iterate through the code

Comment: I changed it to  `if f >= pi`

Comment: Brother, you are plotting single numbers now. If you want to plot what @AnderBiguri plotted, you need to call `f = equation(1:n)` and then `plot(f)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few things you are doing wrong. First, you aren't keeping track of the running sum, you are just defining each term inside the loop. You should instead have something like

```
function total = equation(n)
  total = 0;
  for i = 1:n
    total = total + (-1)^i / (2 * i + 1);
    if total > pi
      break;
    end
  end
  total = 4 * total;
end
```

Second, you don't want the `break` statement there. If you plot the partial sums of this series, you can see that it oscillates either side of pi -

[image]

If you break as soon as you have exceeded pi, then you will break too early (after the first term, in fact!)

So your code should look like

```
function total = equation(n)
  total = 0;
  for i = 1:n
    total = total + (-1)^i / (2*i+1);
  end
  total = 4 * total;
end
```

Additionally, this series will only converge to pi if you start it at zero, rather than one -

```
function total = equation(n)
  total = 0;
  for i = 0:n
    total = total + (-1)^i / (2*i+1);
  end
  total = 4 * total;
end
```

Finally, you can simplify dramatically by vectorizing your code -

```
function total = equation(n)
  indices = 0:n;
  total = 4 * sum((-1).^indices ./ (2 * indices + 1));
end
```

Comment: thank you brother ... I tried to do like your code and I got correct answer but when I plot the f I get error in matlab ... please see my edit ... It does not work to plot(f) , what am I doing wrong ?

Comment: Try changing `sum` to `cumsum` if you want to get all partial sums, instead of just the total.

Comment: See @Adriaan's comment on your question

Comment: I do not understand this `f = equation(1:n)` when I write it in matlab it doesnot work

Comment: I think you need to make at least some effort to figure this out on your own! When you call `f = equation(n)` you get a *single number*. Obviously you can't plot a single number. So you need to get an array of numbers to plot. Something like `for i = 1:n, f(i) = equation(i); end`. Does that help?

Comment: I highly recommend that you read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Where I put them in my code ?? I tried it but I get error , I think I put them in wrong position

Comment: ok I am learning myself by doing this example ... if you tell me where I put your code ..thanks

Answer (score 1):

Your code does not make sense: why would you `sum` a single element, then discard the result the next cycle? Your purpose would be better served by:

```
function f = no_kitty_is_my_pi_you_cant_have_it(n)
        %'Sorry for the South Park reference/pun'

        k = 0:n;
        f = 4 * sum((-1).^k ./ (2*k+1));

end
```

And, as side note on MATLAB programming practices: choosing `i` and `j` as names for variables is not a good idea, because these two are built-in functions that give you the imaginary unit (the square root of -1).

Comment: thank you brother ... I got correct answer but when I plot the f I get error in matlab ... please see my edit ... It does not work to plot(f) , what am I doing wrong ?

Comment: @code You want to plot after the function definition `end`ed. Just swap the lines containing `plot` and `end`, and it should be fine.

Comment: I just get a winow without any plot

Comment: @code Actually, you *do* plot something. You plot a single value, which is the approximation of *pi*. Of course, because a line needs at least 2 end-points and you give just one point, you don't see it. :-) Try for a change: `plot(f, 'ok')`.

Comment: now I see it thank you brother .. But if I want to plot a continuous oscillating graph like the shown above from other posts , How can I do it???

Comment: @code Instead of plotting the *sum* of your approximation, you plot the *cumulative sum*: `plot(4*cumsum((-1).^i ./(2*i+1)))`

Answer (score 1):

To add to the rest of the answers. This code will compute all the approximations of pi from `n=1` to `n=100`.

```
n=100;
f=[];
for jj=1:n
    ii=0:jj;
    f=[f 4*sum( ((-1).^ii)./(2.*ii+1)  )];
end;
hold on
plot(f)
plot(1:size(f,2),ones(size(f))*pi)
```

[image]

Comment: thank you brother ... I got correct answer but when I plot the f I get error in matlab ... please see my edit ... It does not work to plot(f) , what am I doing wrong ?

Comment: @code you are solving just 1 f, so its plots just 1 point. In my code I solve a lot of f

Comment: is that the` f[] `which plot your plot oscillating

Comment: @code The x axis in my code represents `n` in your edited equation. so if you run `equation (n)` for n=1 to n= 100, and you plot the result, then you will get my image.

Comment: do you mean I have to write `function f = equation(1:100)` in my code .. please correct it if its wrong ..

Comment: @code you need to do `for ii=1:n; f(ii)=equation(ii); end; plot(f)`